# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateFiles does not exist. Laravel 5.8 submit form

Tags: php, laravel

This is most likely a duplicate question but I have been looking for solutions and can't seem to find one that fixes the issue I have. I have created a function called **validateRequest** which validates all the fields. This function is then called in **store** function `$post = Post::create($this->validateRequest());`  I have made sure in the HTML form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` has been included, but every time a submit a new entry that errors appear. Not sure if I am using the return tap method correctly or something else, really appreciate some help thanks.

```
    public function validateRequest()
    {
        return tap(
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'title' => 'required|string',
                'h1' => 'required|string',
                'page_title' => 'required|string',
                'meta_description' => 'required|string',
                'image' => 'sometimes|files|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000',
                'content' => 'required|string',
                'active' => 'integer'
            ]), function () {

                if (request()->hasFile('image')){
                    request()->validate([
                        'image' => 'sometimes|files|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000',
                    ]);
                }
            // Check if active is ticked
            $validated['active'] = isset(request()->active[0]) ? 1 : 0;

            // Create slug from title
            $validated['slug'] = Str::slug(request()['title'], '-');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "every time a submit a new entry that errors appear." what errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"files"` is not a valid validator, use `file` without "s"

```
   'image' => 'sometimes|files|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000',
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that worked I also realised that I was validating image twice so that was another problem.

Comment: glad to be of any help 